# .Net SqlDataAdapter retrieve identity after insert with default value on column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, identity, sqldataadapter

I need a way to retrieve identity value after insert using SqlDataAdapter.

I tested the following cases:

1. If I run select @@identity after the insert, the value returned is not right if there are other triggers that perform inserts.
2. If I run select scope_identity() AFTER the insert, it's not the same batch, so the identity is null
3. The solution was to run select scope_identity() in the same batch, so I modified the InsertCommand of adapter (see the code below)

At this point, I encountered another problem: adapter.Update resets the insert command, so it doesn't run the second select (scope_identity()).
If the builder cleans the command with builder.RefreshSchema(), this problem is solved because the insert Command remains unaltered. On the other hand,
if the insert is that:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clinics].[InstutionContracts] ( [DateStart], [DateEnd], [ContractType], [DataDeTest]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as SkunkIdReturn"
```

SQL Server column DataDeTest does not allow nulls, but it has default value of getdate(), so it throws exception of NULL value inserted ( @p4 is NULL). 
    Remember that in this case I run before builder.RefreshSchema(). If I hadn't run this, adapter would update only the first three columns,
the row would be inserted corectly, but I didn't get the identity in table.Rows[0]. Here is my code:

```
DbCommand command = null;
DbDataAdapter adapter = null;

command = new SqlCommand();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

var factory = bProviderFactories.GetFactory("system.data.sqlclient");

var builder = factory.CreateCommandBuilder();
builder.DataAdapter = adapter;

DbCommand command2 = null;
command2 = new SqlCommand();
command2 = builder.GetInsertCommand();
builder.RefreshSchema();  

command2.CommandText += ";SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as SkunkIdReturn"; // get id
adapter.InsertCommand = command2;

var table = new DataTable(tableName);
retSupd.rows = new List<row>();
var lrv = new List<row>();

.... 

var identity = "";

if (isSqlServerConnection && curRow.status == Status.Nou)
{

    adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
    adapter.Update(table);
    identity = table.Rows[0][table.Rows[0].ItemArray.Length - 1].ToString(); // is retrieved only if there are not null values on default columns
    // otherwise, it returns "cannot insert NULL value in not NULL columns" because the insert command is not adapted

}
else
{
    adapter.Update(table); // it works (even on default value columns), but I don't get the identity
}
```

So, how can I retrieve the identity without getting NULL value errors on columns with default value? It wouldn't be right to modify the insert by getting rid
of every column that does not allow NULLs but have default value property.

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
--Display the value of LocationID in the last row in the table.  
SELECT MAX(LocationID) FROM Production.Location;  
GO  
INSERT INTO Production.Location (Name, CostRate, Availability, ModifiedDate)  
VALUES ('Damaged Goods', 5, 2.5, GETDATE());  
GO  
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';  
GO
```

from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: "If the statement fires one or more triggers that perform inserts that generate identity values, calling @@IDENTITY immediately after the statement returns the last identity value generated by the triggers." that's not what I want. Also, Select MAX(ID) would generate inconsistency due to multiple users that perform inserts.